# What is the relationship between wvdial, pon and chat?

Tags: modem, ppp, wvdial, chat-command

I've checked their man pages, but I'm still confused. I just know they are all related to `ppp` connections.

I'm surprised that when I googled "pon wvdial relationship", I get no useful results, so I ask this question here.

Who can tell me the role of these three tools? I still feel they do the same thing... and... I find that a new tool - `pon.wvdial` has come out, and what is it?

I'm really confused with these tools...

Comment: This tutorial might help: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPPP.html

Comment: Also the wvdial wikipedia page is a good resource for linking to all the various pieces (pppd, wvdial, chat, etc.): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WvDial

Comment: Just to add one more interesting program/daemon: [ModemManager](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ModemManager/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### chat & pppd

`chat` is a program that the `pppd` program can use to dial a modem connection.  It is provided with a script of that describes the conversation required to establish the connection.  (A conversation in this context is a series of commands issued by chat, and responses received from the modem.)

#### pon & poff

`pon` and `poff` are commands used to start and stop `ppp` connections.  Starting the connection may use the `chat` program.

#### wvdial

`wvdial` is an intelligent program which automatically establishes a `ppp` connection.  It is used instead of `pon`, `chat`, and `poff` to manage the connection.  `wvdial` also performs the conversation required to establish the connection.  `wvdial` can be configured to automatically disconnect idle connections.